# ons-list の特定行のみ、アイコンを表示したい

Tags: css, onsen-ui, angularjs

ons-listの特定行(１～３行目)のみアイコンを表示したいのですが、
どのようにすればよいでしょうか。

OnsenUI v2とAngularJS v1で開発しております。
ご教授のほど、よろしくお願い致します。

```
    <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item  ng-repeat="data in dataList ">
        <div>
            <!-- ↓アイコン画像を１～３行目のみ表示 -->
            <img src="test.jpg"/>
        </div>
            <span>{{data.name}}</span>
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat`ディレクティブ内では[特殊な値](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)が使用できます。
その中で`$index`は`ng-repeat`ディレクティブ要素のインデックス値を示すため、この値を利用することで特定の順番の要素に変化をつけられます。
要素の表示/非表示には`ng-if`ディレクティブ、または`ng-show`ディレクティブなどを使用すると良いでしょう。

```
<!-- $indexが0〜2の場合に表示 -->
<img ng-if="$index < 3" src="test.jpg"/>
```

Comment: 上記の通りで出来ました！maotさん、ありがとうございます！